# Apache Commons Configuration get property based on parent with attribute equal to value

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-config

I'm using Apache Commons Configuration with XML for the configuration of my application, and I'm having trouble getting a property that I want.

I have the following XML structure (minimal structure just to get point across):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    <planets>
        <planet name="mars">
            <terrain>terrain/mars.terrain</terrain>
        </planet>
        <planet name="earth">
            <terrain>terrain/earth.terrain</terrain>
        </planet>
    </planets>
</settings>
```

As I understand it, the best I can do here to get the mars `terrain` setting is:

```
config.getProperty("planets.planet(0).terrain");
```

Unfortunately, my app doesn't/shouldn't have any concept of the indexes of these planets. At least, the indexes aren't going to be consistent. They could change at any time, so it's *unreliable* to refer to them by index as is done above.

So, what I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
config.getProperty("planets.planet[@name=mars].terrain");
```

That doesn't work, as you might have guessed. The only other way I've found to do it is obtuse and unacceptable:

```
List<Object> planets = config.getList("planets.planet[@name]");

String terrain = "";
for (int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) {
    if (planets[i].toString().equals("mars")) {
        terrain = config.getString("planets.planet(" + i + ").terrain");
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm sure you can see why that's undesirable. Now, I'm to the point where I'm considering just wrapping/extending the Apache Commons Configuration library in order to add this type of functionality, but I'm just unwilling to accept that there isn't an easier way to do this.

#### Question Revisited

What am I overlooking, and how can this be accomplished in a simpler manner? Does this functionality simply not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I could replace the DefaultExpressionEngine with an [XPathExpressionEngine](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html#The_XPATH_expression_engine).

```
XMLConfiguration.setDefaultExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine());
```

This allowed me to use XPath to get my properties, and I could now do:

```
String terrainFile = config.getString("planets/planet[@name='mars']/terrain");
```

One thing to note is that you need the Apache Commons JXPath lib to use the XPathExpressionEngine, or you will get an error when you try to create it.